# compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "WSS_Content",

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

Follwing is my code which uses RunWithElevatedPrivileges in a visual web part

```
SPServiceContext serverContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(currentSite);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serverContext);
UserProfile profile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(currentAccountName);

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(profile.PersonalUrl.AbsoluteUri))
{
   foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
   {
       .....
   }
}
```

It throws an exception when it comes to site.Allwebs and says:
`There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "WSS_Content", and connections to the data have been blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version and build level to return to compatibility range.`

I have read a lot of articles on Internet and tested install last updates for SP but still getting this error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, has your database pending upgrades, look for the database status on Central Admin > Manage Servers in this farm

Comment: the status is "No Action required" for all databases

Comment: Provide few more background details, from when this is happening, Is the site migrated from sharepoint 2007 to 2010.

Comment: No, it is not a migration project. It is a single SharePoint Farm Visual Studio 2012 project which contains only one visual web part. the above code.

Comment: Check if oyu can manually upgrade with this SharePoint Powershell: Upgrade-SPContentDatabase. Or try to run the SharePoint Product Configuration Wizard (PSCONFIG)

Comment: I've also seen this error when a service application account (in this case, perhaps the app pool account, but IME this happened with Excel and Access Services) can't access the DB at all. Can you check to see if the app pool account and the farm account all have access to the DB?

Comment: if you remove the web part does the error go away?  Also is this a brand new web part or one you've upgrade from a previous version of SharePoint?

Comment: PSCONFIG is a must if you have installed updates, make sure it doesn't fail (check logs)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried increase the permissions(dbowner)  for the App Pool Identity on CONTENT DB and the problem got resolved.

Error I got while issuing disable-spfeature is as below
**There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "WSS_Content_CEDintra", and connections to the data have b
een blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web
server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version a
nd build level to return to compatibility range.**

Comment: In SharePoint 2013, application pool account can be given SP_Data_Access permissions as described in this msdn article http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678863.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You should ensure the following:

- If there are any outstanding updates on the farm so make sure to run: `psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait`

  Use the Upgrade-SPContentDatabase cmdlet to resume a failed database upgrade or begin a build to build database upgrade against a SharePoint content database: `Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content`
- Check the application pool identity of the Web Part and the my site
  and user profiles databases, and see if they are different?. Ensure service accounts have
  required access.
- Check the ULS/profile trace while debugging the code.

Comment: When I run psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait it says:Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.

An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException was thrown.  Additional exception information: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SPUpgradeSession Name=Upgrade-20130619-155230-143 was update
d by MOGUL\kourosh.saleh, in the PSCONFIG (9452) process, on machine SRV-2013-KOSA.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict.

Comment: and when I run Upgrade-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content it says: WARNING: Database [SPContentDatabase Name=WSS_Content] does not need to be upgraded.

Comment: I don't understand exactly the third option. "Ensure Required access" where? all has full control permision on User Profile application service.